# Why does the UIAlertController not allow the camera from coming up on iOS 12?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios12

I'm having an issue where while when the thumbnail is tapped, this action works.

```
-(IBAction)thumbnailTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    if (_customItem.file.isEmpty)
    {
        [self openCamera];   // opens camera if no image is present
    }
    else
    {
        _isTransitioningToFullViewOrCamera = true;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CustomFileViewFromItem" sender:self];  // if file is present then it shows the picture blown up.
    }
}
```

and the following code is called:

```objectivec
-(void) openCamera
{
    _isTransitioningToFullViewOrCamera = true;
    NSString *ext = _customItem.file ? _customItem.file.ext : JpgExt;
    if ([CustomCameraController isCameraAvailableForExt:ext forViewController:self])
        [CustomCameraController launchCameraForExt:ext forViewController:self];
}
```

but when called from a UIAlertAction, the camera does not open at all.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet;
actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select an action:" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {      
    // Cancel button tappped.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Replace" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {              
    self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
    [self openCamera];
                        
}]];

// Present action sheet.
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if `[self openCamera]` is placed within the completion block or not, it doesn't change anything.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this; when the UIAlertController is not present (such as with single tap) the `[self openCamera]` opens up the camera and you can take a picture; however when called after the UIAlertController is presented this the camera will not open and fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

"Ask and you shall receive"

there should be a maxim when you've been running up against a wall for days with no answers, only to ask the question and then find the answer on your own.

The answer was to comment out

```
//self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
//    }];
```

as it dismisses the view that contains the `openCamera` function.

I can't believe i didn't realize that until now.

Mission accomplished though! :)